# How to estimate NMOS Cds+Cdb capacitance from VDMOS Pspice/LTSpice model?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, spice, flyback, resonant-converter

I'm designing a fly-back converter and in order to calculate the switching frequency I want to know a method or formula of how estimate the Cds+Cdb capacitance of NMOS switch using the Pspice parameters given by the VDMOS pspice model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you're already using a simulator, you can always set up your test case and actually get usable numbers by measuring yourself.

Comment: Which NMOS switch? A self constructed one or commercially available one?

Comment: This is a commercial one, the STN3N45K3.